# get the 10 highest ints from an average function Django

Tags: django-models, django-views

I want to pass in the albums with the 10 highest reviews, but because it's a function and not part of the model, Django gives a field error, how to resolve this?

Views code:

```py
def homeview(request):
    highest_rated = albums.objects.aggregate(Max("averageReview"))[:10]
    album = albums
    return render(request, "home/home.html", {'album' : album})
```

model code:

```py
class albums(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    release_date = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genre = models.CharField(choices=GENRE_CHOICES, max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default2.jpg', upload_to='album_pics')

    def averageReview(self):
        reviews = ReviewRating.objects.filter(album=self, status=True).aggregate(average=Avg('rating'))
        avg = 0
        if reviews['average'] is not None:
            avg = float(reviews['average'])
        return avg
    

    
class ReviewRating(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(albums, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    review = models.TextField(max_length=1500, blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject or f"ReviewRating #{self.pk}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only query the database for its fields. Therefore aggregate and annotate only work with your model fields, not with the model's properties or methods.

Therefore you would get your queryset and then run the method:

```py
def homeview(request):
    all_albums = albums.objects.all()  # try to reduce the ammount of albums as much as you can
    ratings = [alb.averageReview() for alb in all_albums]  # gets all the average ratings in one list
    idx_of_highest_rated = sorted(range(len(ratings)), key=lambda i: ratings[i])[-10:]  # gets the indices of the 10 highest ratings in list
    best_albums = all_albums[idx_of_highest_rated]  # filters the albums with the indices of highest values for average rating
    return render(request, "home/home.html", {'best_albums' : best_albums})
```

I know this is not ideal in case you really want to scan **all** albums. For smaller queries this is the way to go.

I guess one way to optimize this for bigger queries would be `F()` [expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model). F expressions allow math operations and get translated to SQL which is faster than python.

Try to get comfortable with reverse lookups. For example:

```py
class albums(models.Model):
    [...]

    def averageReview(self):
        reviews = self.reviewrating_set.aggregate(average=Avg('rating'))  # changes here
        avg = 0
        if reviews['average'] is not None:
            avg = float(reviews['average'])
        return avg
```

This should also be much faster, because start of the lookup are not all the reviews, but just the reviews of that specific album. See some examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships). It is a bit hidden, just search for "_set" because that is the syntax for reverse lookups.